# How to copy elements in java array-list?

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist

I have an array-list with different sports. I created my for loop to search trough array-list then I have to copy my element from gfList to gfResult what I'm gonna pass to activity. On the very end is my array-list. I do not know where I have to pass my result inside of switch statement or in the private void part for each activity and how that suppose to be. Thanks in advance! Here is my code what I have but does not work:

```
GroupedFeed findFeed(String locateSport){ 
                if ((!gfList.isEmpty())){
                    public static void main(String args[]){
                    int [] gfList= new int[ gfResult.length ] ;
                    for (int i = 0; i != gfList.size();i++){
                        if (gfList.get(i).category.equalsIgnoreCase(locateSport)){
                           gfResult = Array.copyOf(gfList, gfList.length);
                        }
                        return gfResult;
                    }
                 }
                return null;
               }
        }


        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                    android.view.View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    long id) {
                switch (groupPosition)
                {
                case 0:
                        switch (childPosition)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            // gfResult = findFeed("Men's Baseball");
                            if(gfResult != null){
                                Baseball();
                            }
                              // pass gfResult
                            break;
                          }
                return false;
            }

            private void Baseball() {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Baseball.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
```

Array-list xml file:

```
 this   Main  (id=831962574768) 
groupedFeeds    ArrayList  (id=831963150464)    
    array   Object[12]  (id=831963153088)   
        [0] GroupedFeed  (id=831963152968)  
            category    "Women's Golf" (id=831962986192)    
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963152992)    
        [1] GroupedFeed  (id=831963153592)  
            category    "Volleyball" (id=831962991720)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963153616)    
        [2] GroupedFeed  (id=831963153744)  
            category    "Men's Soccer" (id=831962996544)    
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963153768)    
        [3] GroupedFeed  (id=831963153896)  
            category    "Women's Soccer" (id=831963006320)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963153920)    
        [4] GroupedFeed  (id=831963154864)  
            category    "Men's Golf" (id=831963016488)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963154888)    
        [5] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155072)  
            category    "Men's Cross Country" (id=831963036816) 
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155096)    
        [6] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155224)  
            category    "Women's Cross Country" (id=831963041984)   
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155248)    
        [7] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155472)  
            category    "Men's Bowling" (id=831963093056)   
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155496)    
        [8] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155712)  
            category    "Women's Bowling" (id=831963098224) 
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155736)    
        [9] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155864)  
            category    "Women's Basketball" (id=831963170720)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155888)    
        [10]    GroupedFeed  (id=831963157504)  
            category    "Men's Basketball" (id=831963299944)    
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963157528)    
        [11]    null    
    modCount    11  
    size    11  
loader  RSSLoader  (id=831962575480)    
aMan    AssetManager  (id=831962469744)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Collection class and its subclass such as ArrayList. Their sizes are dynamically allocated and you don't have to allocate just-enough array size every time. E.g.:

```
Vector<Integer> list=new Vector<Integer>();
```

adding element to it

```
list.add(123);
list.add(133);
```

export to an array

```
Integer out[]=list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```